# Como realizar consulta SQL deslocada de 1 posição?

Tags: sql, query

Estou tentando realizar uma consulta onde em uma das colunas (`COTA_DIA_ANTERIOR`) me retorne o valor do dia anterior. Mas está trazendo o valor do dia.

```
SELECT 
    ET.DT_REFERENCIA
   ,ET.VL_PU 
   ,(SELECT TOP (1) [DT_REFERENCIA]  FROM [TRUST].[dbo].[MTM_RFIXA] WHERE [NR_ATIVO] = ET.NR_ATIVO AND DT_REFERENCIA < ET.DT_REFERENCIA ORDER BY DT_REFERENCIA DESC) as DIA_ANTERIOR                                                                
   ,(SELECT TOP(1) ET.VL_PU  FROM MTM_RFIXA WHERE  DT_REFERENCIA  =  (SELECT TOP (1) [DT_REFERENCIA]  FROM [TRUST].[dbo].[MTM_RFIXA] WHERE [NR_ATIVO] = ET.NR_ATIVO AND DT_REFERENCIA < ET.DT_REFERENCIA ORDER BY DT_REFERENCIA DESC) as COTA_DIA_ANTERIOR

FROM MTM_RFIXA ET

WHERE
NR_ATIVO = '2002'

GROUP BY DT_REFERENCIA, VL_PU
ORDER BY DT_REFERENCIA DESC
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Esta usando SQL Server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para quem utiliza SQL Server tem duas funções muito interessantes para serem usadas nesse tipo de consulta. São elas LEAD e LAG. No SQL Server ele armazena a última e a próxima linha da consulta e através dessas funções podemos acessa-las.

> LEAD: Pega a próxima linha;
>
> LAG: Retorna a linha anterior.

Bem, fiz um exemplo aqui usando uma tabela parecida com a que você tem e creio que devido a ordenação decrescente precisei utilizar o LEAD para trazer o resultados. Veja o exemplo:

```
SELECT ET.DT_REFERENCIA
      , LEAD(ET.VL_PU OVER(ORDER BY ET.DT_REFERENCIA DESC)) AS ValorAnterior
      , LEAD(ET.DT_REFERENCIA OVER(ORDER BY ET.DT_REFERENCIA DESC)) AS DataAnterior

      FROM MTM_RFIXA ET
     WHERE NR_ATIVO = '2002'
```

Você também pode fazer alguns testes, substituindo o LEAD por LAG e mudando a ordenação da consulta.

Fonte: [Função LEAD e LAG](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/pt-br/contents/articles/10272.sql-2012-funcoes-lead-e-lag.aspx)

OBS: Caso esteja usando outra base de dados para consultas, eu altero minha resposta.

Comment: Obrigado! Fiz algumas alterações na sua sugestão e funcionou.